# ModRewrite and folder with timestamp

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to forbid users access to a certain folder that has the current date in the folder name.

This does not work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder%{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

This does (considering today is 2015-11-16)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder20151116
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Comment: Have you tried enabling the rewrite log?  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog  You'll need the `RewriteLog /path/to/log/file.log` and `RewriteLogLevel 3` directives

Comment: Also, if you hard code it (like your second code block) does that work?

Comment: Yes, it works hard coded.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog The rewrite condition would be of the form `RewriteCond TestString CondPattern`

> TestString is a string which can contain ... expanded
>   constructs in addition to plain text

and

> CondPattern is the condition pattern, a regular expression which is
>   applied to the current instance of the TestString. TestString is first
>   evaluated, before being matched against CondPattern.

According to that you are only allowed to use the date constructs in the `TestString` not the `CondPattern`.